# Using Sierra to make telephone calls

Tags: macos

When I try to call my iPhone from my Mac having upgraded to Sierra, it keep on asking for my password ... what pass word?

Comment: When you say "try to call my iPhone," do you mean you are dialing the phone number of your iPhone, or you are trying to make calls _with_ your iPhone?

Answer (score 3):

Your Mac uses your phone's cellular connection to place the call. What's happening is that your are calling yourself, which most mobile operators parse as dialing into voicemail. What you hear is a request for your voicemail PIN. If you dial your own number from your iPhone, you'll hear the same request.

Comment: +1 That might be the case - let's see if the OP can narrow down what they're doing.